# python xpath: Compare dates

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xml.etree

I have this simplified xml with a lot of `A` elements:

```
<root>      
    <A class="a" version="7">
      <details>
          <dates>
            <status date="2013-04-29T04:16:49.792-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
            <status date="2013-08-12T04:08:23.773-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
          </dates>
      </details>
    </A>
    <A class="a" version="7">
     ...
</root>
```

**How do I get only those `A` elements that the last status date is greater than a specific timepoint using lxml xpath.**

What I have done so far:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("./my.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
res = root.xpath("A[./details/dates/status[last()]/@date > '2013-08-12T00:00:0.000-04:00' ]");
```

But the problem with this code is that the comparison returns always *false* for some reason, so the `res` is always *empty*.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to translate and compare as numbers:

```
In [24]: x = """<root>
   ....:     <A class="a" version="7">
   ....:       <details>
   ....:           <dates>
   ....:             <status date="2013-04-29T04:16:49.792-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
   ....:             <status date="2013-08-12T04:08:23.773-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
   ....:           </dates>
   ....:       </details>
   ....:     </A>
   ....:     <A class="a" version="7">
   ....: </root>"""

In [25]: from lxml import html


In [26]: xml = html.fromstring(x)


In [27]: print(xml.xpath("a[translate(./details/dates/status[last()]/@date,'-:T.','') > '201308120000000000400']"))
[<Element a at 0x7fdb45bc8aa0>]
```

it will  be fine to compare once you are always comparing dates with the same offset and you have the same amount of digits as your dates are in iso8601 format with the yyyy-mm-dd format so it is safe to compare, if you have different offsets or numer of digits then  you are  going to have to compare as datetime objects.

Comment: I fear this will not work as expected because off number representation in xpath/lxml (ass floating point). This will be `2.01308120408e+20.` Therefor it need to be more a more complex xapth (e.g comparing date `substring-before(...,'T')` and  than time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no date type in xpath 1.0 and you cannot compare strings in xpath 1.0 with operators other than `=` and `!=`. You've got a package that supports a part of xpath 2 in python but i've never tried it (see [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml-xpath2-functions/0.0.3)). It may be a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `datutil.parser`:

```
from lxml import etree
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

a = '''<root>      
    <A class="a" version="7">
      <details>
          <dates>
            <status date="2013-04-29T04:16:49.792-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
            <status date="2013-08-12T04:08:23.773-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
          </dates>
      </details>
    </A>
    <A class="b" version="8">
      <details>
          <dates>
            <status date="2012-04-29T04:16:49.792-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
            <status date="2012-08-12T04:08:23.773-04:00">ACCEPTED</status>
          </dates>
      </details>
    </A>
 </root> '''

tree = etree.fromstring(a)

# Set your begin time
beginTime = parse('2013-08-12T00:00:0.000-04:00')

# Loop through all A elements
for A in tree.findall('A'):
    # Get the last time of the A element
    timeA = A.find('./details/dates/status[last()]')   

    # Parse the found date into a datetime element
    date = parse(timeA.get('date'))

    # Compare the beginTime with the found date
    if beginTime < date:

        # Do as you like
        #print(date)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a slow way to do the thing